# Need suggestions for formulating an architecture for deep neural network

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I am relatively new to the field of deep learning.

The problem I am trying to model is one where I have a corpus of calls. The call has two participants.

My goal is to classify an instance where vulnerability is present (I refer to vulnerability as being a sign of being distraught, hopeless, anxious and sentiments alike. ) Given the vulnerability bit, I have to classify the ensuing dialogues for empathy. If the vulnerability isn't found, I needn't look for empathy.

So far I have been doing this in a sequential manner, such that once I get a positive vulnerability from the first classifier, only then do I use my second classifier and classify the ensuing dialogues for empathy. If this isn't the case, i.e if vulnerability isn't found I don't bother looking for empathy and just decide to not use my empathy classifier.

I have trained the classifiers on separate datasets And they act independently.

Now someone suggested me that I should use a hybrid architecture using the keras functional api. They pointed out to me that these both classifiers could be input layers where their outputs (going through some pooling layers and such) should go as an concatenated input layer to a third model which learns the combination of vulnerability and empathy in unison rather than the manner I had been modeling it in.

My question is, does this make sense? Should I let the third model learn from the combination of these two models while clearly one necessitates the use of another..

I am confused about trying this idea out. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: there is no real truth that can answer this question, If you are able to implement such a model, then go ahead and check the performance relative to your initial approach. Besides some general assumption, you can't predict the behaviour of a network based on the architecture alone.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your skepticism on this suggested alteration. If it were always performing two or more operations per one data point (as in common object detection networks), then that might simplify the system. In your case, however, it sounds like the output of the first network determines whether the second network *is even used,* which is a desirable efficiency. I would keep it the way you have it.

Remember that the difference between 'two networks' and 'a two-layer network' is entirely arbitrary. Using the functional api (graph notation) we can think and speak of things as operationally parallel, but they are nevertheless executed sequentially. In other words, the only major operational difference between your current method and the method suggested is this: your method only calls the second model when necessary.